# Does any airline offer some "gamer" seats?

Tags: air-travel, airlines

I read on https://www.cnn.com/travel/a380-global-airlines/index.html:

> Gone are the plans for a “gamer class” — seats equipped with Xbox and PlayStation consoles — which the airline was mulling about last year

This made me wonder: does any airlines offer some "gamer" seats?

Comment: On my last long flight a few weeks ago the seats had a video screen and a tethered game controller. I didn’t try to play anything. I suspect the available games are not real gamer material.

Comment: Unlikely for airlines given their weight, but [some pilots definitely like them](https://twitter.com/PilotoF22/status/1343205890875404288)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [alternativeairlines.com](https://www.alternativeairlines.com/global-airlines#:%7E:text=Global%20Airlines%20has%20plans%20to,1%2D3%2D1%20configuration.), no airlines offer some "gamer" seats (emphasis mine):

> Global Airlines has plans to be the **first airline** to introduce a new and exclusive 'Gamer Class'.